# Show the local session through xrdp remote desktop

Tags: x11, remote-desktop, xrdp

I have a Linux machine (computer A, Debian 8). I installed xrdp there (configuration is default). Now I can run remote desk from two windows machines (computer B and C) to reach computer A. However, the desktop I saw from windows machine is different from the one in computer A's monitor. For example, there is a terminal opened in computer A. When I run remote desktop from computer B, I did not see the opened terminal. If I start a new terminal from computer B by remote desktop, this new terminal window is not shown in computer A's monitor. If I run remote desktop from computer C, I can see the terminal window opened by computer B.

My goal is that the desktop shown in computer A's monitor and desktops shown by remote desktop from computer B and C should display the same content. How should I configure to achieve the goal?

RDP file:

```
screen mode id:i:2
use multimon:i:0
desktopwidth:i:1920
desktopheight:i:1080
session bpp:i:32
winposstr:s:0,3,0,0,800,600
compression:i:1
keyboardhook:i:2
audiocapturemode:i:0
videoplaybackmode:i:1
connection type:i:7
networkautodetect:i:1
bandwidthautodetect:i:1
displayconnectionbar:i:1
enableworkspacereconnect:i:0
disable wallpaper:i:0
allow font smoothing:i:0
allow desktop composition:i:0
disable full window drag:i:1
disable menu anims:i:1
disable themes:i:0
disable cursor setting:i:0
bitmapcachepersistenable:i:1
full address:s:192.168.1.21
audiomode:i:0
redirectprinters:i:1
redirectcomports:i:0
redirectsmartcards:i:1
redirectclipboard:i:1
redirectposdevices:i:0
autoreconnection enabled:i:1
authentication level:i:2
prompt for credentials:i:0
negotiate security layer:i:1
remoteapplicationmode:i:0
alternate shell:s:
shell working directory:s:
gatewayhostname:s:
gatewayusagemethod:i:4
gatewaycredentialssource:i:4
gatewayprofileusagemethod:i:0
promptcredentialonce:i:0
gatewaybrokeringtype:i:0
use redirection server name:i:0
rdgiskdcproxy:i:0
kdcproxyname:s:
username:s:michael
```

Comment: One way is to use a vnc server that starts with the display manager, the login screen. When you can vnc into the machine and login to a desktop, as it is mirrored on the monitor, you are most of the way there.

Comment: Oh I think you can use the X11rdp back-end too, but you must 'tell it' what display to use. Example the monitor is usually display 0. BTW: In my experience the X11rdp back-end runs smoother. I am doing this from memory, but I think its in the `sesman.ini` file